# How does the Schwarzchild interior solution dodge the singularity theorems?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, astrophysics, metric-tensor, singularities

The [Schwarzchild interior solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Schwarzschild_metric) is a static solution with no singularity which can be coupled to the Schwarzchild exterior to obtain a static, singularity-free universe. How does this universe dodge the Hawking-Penrose singularity theorems? There is no exotic matter or anything like that, that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is matched to the normal, exterior, solution at a radius greater than the Schwarzschild radius: thus there is no event horizon.  So it is a (considerably idealised) solution that might describe something like a star, where the vacuum part of the field is the traditional Schwarzschild solution, but the field in the interior is not: consider the Sun, say.

Comment: And if it is matched to the exterior solution _inside_ the Schwarzchild radius then there is an event horizon and then a singularity theorem does apply?  Which means that the solution can longer be static and collapse is inevitable?

Comment: @DzamoNorton It can't be matched inside the horizon, it has terms like $\sqrt{1-R_S/R_m}$ in it, where $R_m$ is the surface radius and $R_S$ the Schwarzschild radus.

Comment: Thank you @tfb.  Last question!  So when a _real_ ball of dust collapses through R=2M it is forced to go from having (approximately) a Schwarzchild interior solution to having some other interior solution?

Comment: Ah, never mind @tfb.  A _collapsing_ ball of dust is not static so it never had the Schwarzchild interior solution to start with.  I think the penny has finally dropped!

Comment: @DzamoNorton Exactly!

Comment: @DzamoNorton: a collapsing homogeneous ball of dust is described by the Oppenheimer-Snyder metric.